# PHP Project Organisation and Deployment (FuelPHP)

Tags: php, fuelphp, file-organization

This project is using the FuelPHP framework but the question is around organisation of files.

My file structure is as follows:

```
/fuel
   /app
      /assets
      ...
/public
```

I current have assets.mydomain.com pointing to /fuel/app/assets but where would I place user content files such as profile pictures, etc.

In terms of deployment, I have never deployed a project like this before and I need some way of automating it, (using rsync or something). I wondered if anyone could recommend a way I can do this without wiping user files.

Comment: why you change the assets path? The folder assets by default is located inside of public folder

Comment: it doesn't matter because the web server is setup to have them on a subdomain anyway

Comment: installing your code inside the docroot isn't exactly best practice...

Comment: @WanWizard Where would you recommend putting uploaded files (from users etc) and assets which would sit on a cookie-less subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, I kept the assets directory under public. User content is stored in the media directory:

```
/public
    /assets
    /media
```

Regarding deployment, I use a simple git workflow: I have a bare git repo on my target server  and a post-receive hook that checkout the branch in the working directory under my docroot.
To deploy, I just push from my local repo to the bare remote.

More details here: http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto